# date range in drupal-6 view arguments?

Tags: drupal, arguments, drupal-views, date-range

I have a view which loads certain goods elements on the view based upon start date and end date, what i need is a date range. Unfortunately in drupal arguments there is no range and filtering option.

I'm using only one table in mysql, which receive from and two date and returns specific items.

I tried this code, but it's not working. Is there any date-range filter which does the job or should I write my own filter?

```
function abc_display_screen() {
  $viewName = 'abc';
  $arg = '2008-01-04--2014-02-04';
  $viewsHtml .= views_embed_view($viewName, 'default', $arg);
  return $viewsHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not use two filters instead?

Filter by dates below x and above y ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module may do this for you. It has some views integration and I belive that this is something it does. However the versions you are using may cause some integration headaches at the moment.